# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ItemizedOverlay

Tags: android

I have a MapView with lots of overlay markers on it. It kind of works but tends to ANR when the markers are being added as there are a lot of them. So I've moved the code into an AsyncTask. Once moved, the code breaks, with the following exception bubbling up from the framework when the rendering is done. The error  seems to be intermittent, but the more overlay items there are the more often it occurs.

What's causing the exception? How can I work around it?

```
11-24 12:40:44.316: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=2
    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getIndexToDraw(ItemizedOverlay.java:211)
    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.draw(ItemizedOverlay.java:240)
    at com.company.myapp.MyOverlay.draw(TaxiOverlay.java:43)
    at com.google.android.maps.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:179)
    at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:530)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10982)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2899)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2106)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1613)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my class:

```
public class MarkersMapView extends MapView {

public void showMarkers() {
    new showMarkersTask().execute();
}

public void clearMarkersFromMap() {
    this.getOverlays().remove(markersOverlay);
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_map_marker);
    markersOverlay = new MarkerOverlay(drawable, this);
    getOverlays().add(availableMarkersOverlay);
}

class showMarkersTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    showTheMarkers();
    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void v) {
    invalidate();
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
}

private void showTheMarkers() {
    Marker[] markers = Marker.getMarkerList();
    if (markers == null || markers.length == 0) return;
    clearMarkersFromMap();
    for (User marker : markers) {
        showMarker(marker.location.latitude, marker.location.longitude, marker.location.title, marker.location.subtitle);
        publishProgress();
    }
}

public void showMarker(float latitude, float longitude, String markerTitle, String markerSubtitle) {
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1000000), (int) (longitude * 1000000));
    OverlayItem marker = new OverlayItem(point, markerTitle, markerSubtitle);
    markersOverlay.addOverlay(marker);
    MarkerMapView.this.postInvalidate();
}

}
}
```

Comment: Scroll down, I've included the code already.

Comment: If you want to avoid ANR you should use less markers, give the user option to toggle markers off etc. And I was right all along, thx for -1 for trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't the access to the list of items be done on the ui thread? during the onPostProgress maybe?

and clearMarkersFromMap() during onPreExecute?

Comment: Thanks, you were right. It seems that adding items to overlays in doInBackground() is prone to problems. I moved it to onProgressUpdate() and it works fine. I also found a secondary issue where I had more than one asynctask running at once, so it now stops a previous one before starting a new one. It still ANRs with more than a hundred of so items, but I think it'll do what I need. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

As people suggest, don't try to play with an array whilst its used else where. In this case, don't try to show the markers as they're processed (you can do this, but I'd suggest improving this at a later date once its working), do them all then show the results:

```
public class MarkersMapView extends MapView {

        public void showMarkers() {
            new showMarkersTask().execute();
        }

        public void clearMarkersFromMap() {
            this.getOverlays().remove(markersOverlay);
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_map_marker);
            markersOverlay = new MarkerOverlay(drawable, this);
        }

        class showMarkersTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            showTheMarkers();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            clearMarkersFromMap();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
             getOverlays().add(markersOverlay);
        }

        private void showTheMarkers() {
            Marker[] markers = Marker.getMarkerList();
            if (markers == null || markers.length == 0) return;
            for (User marker : markers) {
                showMarker(marker.location.latitude, marker.location.longitude, marker.location.title, marker.location.subtitle);
            }
        }

        public void showMarker(float latitude, float longitude, String markerTitle, String markerSubtitle) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1000000), (int) (longitude * 1000000));
            OverlayItem marker = new OverlayItem(point, markerTitle, markerSubtitle);
            markersOverlay.addOverlay(marker);
        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldnt update an array in a task if it used somewhere else at the same time.

Comment: What's your suggested solution?

Comment: Split your overlays up into groups, use less markers. Give the user ability to toggle markers.

Comment: Why would I split into groups or reduce, is there a fixed limit? The app blows up even if I have low numbers (<50) of overlays. I believe the exception relates to the use of AsyncTask not the large number of overlays. This is supported by the fact that the app never crashes if the code is moved out of the task.

Comment: You could try to add markers to overlay and then add overlay on the ui thread to map

Comment: To be exact your exception is thrown because you remove content while working with it.

Comment: Yes, but what content? Why isn't the postInvalidate() call working to ensure it doesn't render non-existent items?